# Ruby: Can't extract JSON data by nested key using group_by method

Tags: ruby, regex, json

I am trying to extract JSON objects which include Hotel in line1 of the address, but I keep getting the following error:

```
line1_hotel.rb:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from line1_hotel.rb:4:in `each'
    from line1_hotel.rb:4:in `group_by'
    from line1_hotel.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

My Ruby version is 2.1.4p265, and my code is below. I have used square bracket notation to access data in nested keys before. But in this case it seems to be failing. I've looked at the group_by Ruby doc but there is no detail at all whether it accepts this kind of notation. Also, if I don't nest it works in other examples.

```
require 'json'

array = JSON.parse File.read('gaps4.json')
result = array.group_by do |e|
  e['address']['line1'] =~ /Hotel/ ? true : false
end

File.open('testtrue.json', 'w') do |file|
  file << JSON.pretty_generate(result[true])
end

File.open('testfalse.json', 'w') do |file|
  file << JSON.pretty_generate(result[false])
end
```

An example "snippet" from the JSON data I am trying to extract. For example one object has Hotel in line1 whereas the other doesn't. (There are many records):

```
[
     {
        "id": "242595",
        "name": "San Lorenzo - Wimbledon",
        "phone": "+442089468463",
        "email": "live@sanlorenzo.com",
        "website": "https://sanlorenzosw19.squarespace.com/new-page/",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 51.4221176,
          "longitude": -0.208713,
          "address": {
            "line1": "38 Wimbledon Hill Road",
            "line2": "",
            "line3": "",
            "postcode": "SW19 7PA",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "UK"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "101055",
        "name": "Sanderson",
        "phone": "+442073005588",
        "email": "restaurant.resuk@mhgc.com",
        "website": "",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 51.51747,
          "longitude": -0.13724,
          "address": {
            "line1": "Sanderson Hotel",
            "line2": "50 Berners Street",
            "line3": "",
            "postcode": "W1T 3NG",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "UK"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e['address']['line1']` should be `e['location']['address']['line1']`. Just re-check your `json` structure.

The reason you get an error is that `e['address']` is `nil` and `e['address']['line1']` is a try to call `['line']`, that is in fact `#[]` method, on `nil`.

Plus, whether you are not producing this `json` yourself, it would be fine to protect the code from accidental errors:

```
e['location'] &&              # make sure location given
e['location']['address'] &&   # make sure address given
e['location']['address']['line1'] =~ /Hotel/ ? true : false
```

Just not to fail if no location was presented.

Comment: Ahhhh, that was a silly mistake, thanks for your help @mudasobwa